# No output when debugging File Tayloring using ISPFTTRC

Tags: ispf

I am attempting to debug a small file tailoring job but don't get any output when attempting to use the trace command ISPFTTRC which is described at

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54dg00/ispfttrc.htm#ispfttrc

The REXX interprets without warnings.

I have also tried coding the command as
    "ISPFTTRC LIST"
but this did not work.

I'd like to:

1. Get the ISPFTTRC command to return some output since it will be useful for future debugging.
2. Fix the problem with the job.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Here is the JCL:

```
//DOIT     EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,
//             PARM='ISPSTART CMD(NDRACMQ)'
//SYSPROC  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=&SYSUID..ALL.REXX
//*    --- ISPF FILES ---
//ISPSLIB  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=&SYSUID..ALL.SKELS
//*    --- OUTPUTS ---
//ISPFILE  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=&SYSUID..ALL.SKELS(NDSACMO)   tailored output
//ISPFTTRC DD DISP=SHR,DSN=&SYSUID..ISPFTTRC      debugging output
//*    --- MORE ISPF FILES ---
//ISPPROF  DD DSN=&&ISPPROF,DISP=(NEW,DELETE,DELETE),
//             LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,DSORG=PO,SPACE=(TRK,(2,2,2))  
//ISPPLIB  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=&SYSUID..ALL.PARMLIB        needed? I think not
//ISPTLIB  DD DISP=(NEW,DELETE,DELETE),DSN=&&ISPTLIB,
//             SPACE=(TRK,(1,1,1)),LIKE=SYS1.SYSTLIB
//         DD DISP=SHR,DSN=SYS1.SYSTLIB
//ISPMLIB  DD DISP=SHR,DSN=SYS1.SYSMLIB
//*    --- OTHER FILES ---
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//ABNLDUMP DD DUMMY
//SYSTSIN  DD DUMMY
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*
```

The REXX (simplified):

`/* REXX - Bulk ACM queries */
     ISPFTTRC LIST
     "ISPEXEC FTOPEN"
       ele=aaaaa
     "ISPEXEC FTINCL NDSACMQ"
       ele=bbbbb
     "ISPEXEC FTINCL NDSACMQ"
     "ISPEXEC FTCLOSE"
    exit`

The skeleton code from &SYSUID..ALL.SKELS(NDSACMQ):

```
)CM *-----------------------------------------------------------------*
)CM * Skeleton SCL used to create bulk ACM queries.                   *
)CM *-----------------------------------------------------------------*
   LIST USING COMPONENTS FOR
       ELEMENT  &ELE       ENVIRONMENT   *
       SYSTEM   *          SUBSYSTEM     *
       TYPE     *          STAGE NUMBER  *
   OPTIONS
.
```

Comment: Does `//ISPFTTRC DD DISP=SHR,DSN=&SYSUID..ISPFTTRC` refer to a dataset that meets the following criteria? *Where the ddname ISPFTTRC is preallocated, this data set is used, providing it refers to a sequential, VB data set with a record length of at least 255.* Have you tried `ISPFTTRC VIEW` instead of `ISPFTTRC LIST`? You may also need to code `SKELETON NDSACMQ` e.g. `ISPFTTRC VIEW SKELETON NDSACMQ` (`*` or `ALL` for all skeletons or a mask e.g `NDCA*` for all skeletons starting with NDCA or `NDC%MQ` for all skeletions starting with NDC then any character followed by MQ etc.*)

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike. 

The DSN &SYSID..ISPFTTRC is PS VB 300 so no problem with the dsn attributes.    

I have tried all of the Commands you suggested. i.e.
ISPFTTRC LIST
ISPFTTRC VIEW

Comment: Did you try `ISPFTTRC VIEW SKELETON NDSACMQ`? I'm pretty sure you have to indicate what you want traced.

Comment: Ok I have some output now. I tried many things so I'm not quite sure which one of them solved it. 
What I did was: 
1) Check the RC's in the REXX immediately after ISPFTTRC command. Some of the commands gave RC=8.
2) Reallocated the ISPFTTRC file with a larger LRECL.
3) I then found output in a DSN &SYSUID..**.ISPFT.TRACE that had been dynamically allocated 2 days ago. The output showed the command used was simply "ISPFTTRC" without quotes.
4) I renamed the file at 3) above.
5) I changed my REXX to use just "ISPFTTRC" and voila! output in &SYSUID..ISPFTTRC.

Comment: Thanks for your help, got me thinking again after I was stuck. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Output was going to a dynamically allocated file &SYSUID.**.ISPFT.TRACE.

The way to code the ISPFTTRC command in the REXX was simply "ISPFTTRC" without the quotes, this gives output.

Checking the RC from the command within the REXX was helpful.

I will be able to resolve the problem with the job now that I have trace output.